# Execute command in Hudson as Post-build Actions

Tags: hudson, static-analysis, fortify

I am new in Hudson.
I would like to execute a 'sourcecodeanalyzer' command in Hudson as Post-build Actions to generate an html report. Please let me know is this at all possible, if yes let me know the Hudson configuration steps to execute the command.

Your earliest response in this regard will be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is almost certainly possible.

You will need to configure the Hudson project to have either a post-build action or a build step that runs your source code analyzer.

You've not stated in your question precisely which analyzer - it may be that Hudson already has a plug-in installed for it, in which case it may be listed on the Config page for the project at the bottom under **Post-build Actions**.

If not, next check to see if there's a plug-in available for the analyzer that hasn't been installed. From the main Hudson page select `Manage Hudson`, then `Manage Plugins`, and choose the `Available` tab. If there is a plug-in available it's definitely a good idea to use it as they are generally very well integrated with Hudson itself.

As a last resort you'll have to configure a build step to run the analyzer. Configure the project, then choose "Add build step". The drop-down that appears depends on your environment (Windows or Linux) but should include the ability to run a shell command or batch file. You can configure your analyzer there.

(If you're building Windows Visual Studio applications, a more flexible way that I've used is to use the MSBuild plug-in for builds, and have an MSBuild script that builds the application and then runs analysis tools. This can automate pretty much everything: mine builds the application, builds an acceptance test database, runs the acceptance tests and copies the result HTML to a page linked from the project.)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new job with a "Execute Shell" build step.  Type in the command you wish to run in the text box.  Then all you have to do is trigger this job by selecting:

"Build after other projects are built"

And select the trigger job from the list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to Jeremy's post. If you don't see the ability to add post build steps, you might work with maven jobs. In that case you need the [Hudson M2 Extra Steps Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin). This will give you pre and post build steps.

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'Post build task' plugin to delete some resources after a build. You could call any shell script or command lines. If you want you could make the call depends on some logging output.

Answer (score 0):

there is one best way to solve this:

1. Upgrade to Fortify SCA 2.6.x (as of writing, latest version is 2.6.5).
2. Download the Fortify Maven Plugin version 2.6 from https://customerportal.fortify.com and install it into your Hudson server's Maven repository.
3. Update your project's pom to carry out the Fortify scan.  There is an example provided with the Maven plugin.

Comment: The alternate way to do this is to download the f360 Hudson plugin, but if you are already using Maven2 that is a superior way to integrate Fortify SCA.

Answer (score -1):

Currently , I am experiment with sonar plug in. It looks great check the details here

http://sonar.codehaus.org/a-new-hudson-plugin-for-a-closer-integration-with-sonar/

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin